# Correct handling of drawing multiple objects?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Although I'm technically working in the android platform with OpenGL 2.0 ES, I believe this can be applied to more OpenGL technologies.

I have a list of objects (enemies, characters, etc) that I'm attempting to draw onto a grid, each space being 1x1, and each object matching.  Presently, each object is self translating... that is, it's taking its model coordinates and going through a simple loop to adjust them to be located in the world coordinates in its appropriate grid location.  (i.e. if it should be at (3,2) it will translate it's coordinates accordingly.

The problem I've reached is I'm not sure how to effeciently draw them.  I have a loop going through all the objects and calling draw for each object, similar to the android tutorial, but this seems wildly ineffecient.

The objects are each textured with their own square images, matching the 1x1 grid they fill.  They likely will never need their own unique shaders, so the only thing that seems to change between objects is the verticies and the shaders.

Is there an effecient way to get each model into the pipeline without flushing because of uniform changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably requires some try and error procedure an probably is hardware dependent. I would use buffer objects for the meshes with GL_STATIC_DRAW, pack some textures in a bigger one and draw all objects depending on that bigger texture in batch to avoid states changes as much as possible. Profile and get us more information on where is your bottleneck.

Comment: There is one for each architecture, Adreno SDK, Tegra SDK, etc.